# Why username updated in setInterval doesn't reflect in view

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, settimeout

Why does only count gets updated but not username

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

function ReposGrid({ id }) {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  var username = "Deen";
  let timeId = setInterval(() => {
    setCount(count + 1);
    username = username + count;
    console.log("shows updated username ", username);
  }, 1000);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    document.title = `Hello, ${username} ${count}`; //this updates title everytime but username is still old
  }, [count]);

  console.log("shows old instead of updated username ", username); //doesn't work.doesn't show updated username value

  return <h1>{username}</h1>;
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<ReposGrid />, rootElement);
```

Comment: `count` gets updated because it is declared and updated through `useState`. 

Whereas `username` is just a simple variable inside your `ReposGrid` function.
React can't keep track of it.

Comment: Why do you want to keep the `username` as just a regular variable instead of adding it to the `state`?

Comment: I understood that i can fix this using useState with name but i wanted to know exact reason why it failed without it

Answer (score 1):

The code is following the correct behaviour, let me explain:

1. setInterval is executed and queued in the event queue.
2. Note at this point the code inside it isn't executed but deferred to be executed in 1 sec.
3. Next you enter the `useEffect` function. Note the code inside `setInterval` is still not executed.
4. You update the title here with previous/original value of `username`.
5. Next you console.log previous value of username and return it inside `header` tag.

> *At this point, the code which was in event queue it put back on stack and executed (i.e., atleast after 1 sec).*

6. `setCount(count + 1)` is called. Since state variable got updated, therefore `useEffect` gets executed and the rest of the function too (including updation of title)
7. Now next statement will be executed `username = username + count`. Since this isn't a state variable so even though the variable updates, `useEffect` is not called nor is `document.title` updated.
8. Now username is updated (but no side effects).
9. Next you `console.log("shows updated username ", username)`
10. This should console.log updated value.

Answer (score 0):

It fails because React is unaware of the name variable because as mentioned above it's not part of the state. Therefore you don't see any updates, when using setState.

Answer (score 0):

Littlebit clean up needed. Always use sideeffects with useEffect. Anything u want immediate effect use useLayoutEffect. And follow React way of writting.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

function ReposGrid({ id }) {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  let username = "Dean " ;
  React.useEffect(() => {
    let timeId = setInterval(() => {
      setCount(count + 1);
    }, 1000);
    return () => {
      clearInterval(timeId);
    };
  }, [count]);
  React.useLayoutEffect(() => {
    document.title = `Hello, ${username} ${count}`;
  }, [username, count]);
  console.log("shows old instead of updated username ", username, count); //doesn't work.doesn't show updated username value
  return (
    <h1>
      {username}
      {count}
    </h1>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<ReposGrid />, rootElement);
```

```js
"use strict";

function _slicedToArray(arr, i) { return _arrayWithHoles(arr) || _iterableToArrayLimit(arr, i) || _unsupportedIterableToArray(arr, i) || _nonIterableRest(); }

function _nonIterableRest() { throw new TypeError("Invalid attempt to destructure non-iterable instance.\nIn order to be iterable, non-array objects must have a [Symbol.iterator]() method."); }

function _unsupportedIterableToArray(o, minLen) { if (!o) return; if (typeof o === "string") return _arrayLikeToArray(o, minLen); var n = Object.prototype.toString.call(o).slice(8, -1); if (n === "Object" && o.constructor) n = o.constructor.name; if (n === "Map" || n === "Set") return Array.from(n); if (n === "Arguments" || /^(?:Ui|I)nt(?:8|16|32)(?:Clamped)?Array$/.test(n)) return _arrayLikeToArray(o, minLen); }

function _arrayLikeToArray(arr, len) { if (len == null || len > arr.length) len = arr.length; for (var i = 0, arr2 = new Array(len); i < len; i++) { arr2[i] = arr[i]; } return arr2; }

function _iterableToArrayLimit(arr, i) { if (typeof Symbol === "undefined" || !(Symbol.iterator in Object(arr))) return; var _arr = []; var _n = true; var _d = false; var _e = undefined; try { for (var _i = arr[Symbol.iterator](), _s; !(_n = (_s = _i.next()).done); _n = true) { _arr.push(_s.value); if (i && _arr.length === i) break; } } catch (err) { _d = true; _e = err; } finally { try { if (!_n && _i["return"] != null) _i["return"](); } finally { if (_d) throw _e; } } return _arr; }

function _arrayWithHoles(arr) { if (Array.isArray(arr)) return arr; }

function ReposGrid(_ref) {
  var _ref$username = _ref.username,
      username = _ref$username === void 0 ? "User" : _ref$username;

  var _useState =  React.useState(0),
      _useState2 = _slicedToArray(_useState, 2),
      count = _useState2[0],
      setCount = _useState2[1];

  React.useEffect(function () {
    var timeId = setInterval(function () {
      setCount(count + 1);
    }, 1000);
    return function () {
      clearInterval(timeId);
    };
  }, [count]);
  React.useLayoutEffect(function () {
    document.title = "Hello, ".concat(username, " ").concat(count);
  }, [username, count]);
  console.log("shows old instead of updated username ", username, count); //doesn't work.doesn't show updated username value

  return /*#__PURE__*/React.createElement("h1", null, username, count);
}

var rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render( /*#__PURE__*/React.createElement(ReposGrid, null), rootElement);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.10.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.10.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```